# Passing a URL to TemplateUrl when calling a component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

First app in Angular 2 (newbie), and I am trying to put together a simple blog...everything is working great except for one thing.

To archive potentially hundreds of articles (as they roll off the primary blog), I thought it would make sense to have a single "Archive" component where I pass the URL of the article as either a variable to the component or as a parameter using the router to display the loaded HTML of the particular archived article from a page of archived-article links (and each a unique URL for search-ability). This seems like a much simpler approach than creating hundreds of components, one for each article, and hard-coding each template URL. Any easy way to do it?

Something like this where "article" is a route parameter would have been nice:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'archive/:article', component: MainComponent}
];

<a routerLink="/archive/article1.html".....</a>
<a routerLink="/archive/article2.html".....</a>

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: this.route.snapshot.params['article']  //compiles - doesn't work
})
```

Using ngOnInit() would be great too but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: One way to do a blog is to save the template of your articles and load them with the `innerHtml` attribut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to store you articles in a database. Each article will have a unique id or name.

When you go to the route archive/1 or archive/some-article-name then it will make an api call with the id or name.  The api will then hit the database and return back the article contents.  Then your component will just render the article contents.

Then you can do a ngFor for the archived articles.

```
<a *ngFor="let article of articles" routerLink="/archive/{article.id}".....</a>
```

If you don't have an api/db for articles.  You could just create an array of articles in the angular app itself too.